# Static Files in Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Django Crispy Forms and intend to combine it with Twitter-bootstrap and have already installed crispy forms. I have been using http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/install.html#uni-form-static-files.

My question is I need to include the uni-form files in my HTML code and if so, I don't seem to find the files to include.

What should i do? Need some guidance...

Comment: It would be nice if some one created a django-crispy-forms tag....

Comment: read the docs. there are tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you wanted to use Bootstrap. Uniform is an alternative to that. So you don't need to use these files at all.

Comment: Am i right to say that all i need to call bootstrap css files and call crispy forms where necessary? That will do it? I am not sure that is why i am asking such as stupid question...

Comment: Yes you are right. That is all you need to do. Don't worry. Everybody gets confused from time to time :)

Comment: do u know where to set CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK  = bootstrap? where should this line go to?

Comment: It probably should read `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap'` and it goes in your settings.py

Comment: it goes below:TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG. Am i right? or where should it go?

Answer (score 0):

In case, you like to include the uniform instead of the Bootstrap, what you need to do is

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will collect all the static files and store in uni-form folder., since after installing the crispy-forms, you might not know where the static files are..